# Python - Date conversion

Tags: python, datetime

I'm using Python and I want to convert a date from the following formats:

`'30th Sep 2018'` or `'Mon 30th Sep 2018'`

to the format:

`'2018-09-30 00:00:00'`

I already tried to use the strptime() and strftime() functions but I can't make this works with them.

Anyone know how to accomplish this in Python?

Comment: What have you tried so far? please show us your code.

Comment: @PedroLobito : I used strptime() and strftime() functions but it did not work out.

Comment: HI @Debbie, I edited your question to make it clearer what you're trying to do. Try to put everything that you already and search a little more on the StackOverflow and documentations, that I really think that somebody already made a question similar to this question.

Comment: @coderade : Thanks for the edit. I'll remember your suggestions next time onward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `datetime.strptime` and `datetime.strftime` for that like so:

```
from datetime import datetime

def convert1(string):
    conversion = '%d' + string[2:4] + ' %b %Y'
    dt = datetime.strptime(string, conversion)
    return dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

def convert2(string):
    conversion = '%a %d' + string[6:8] + ' %b %Y'
    dt = datetime.strptime(string, conversion)
    return dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print(convert1('30th Sep 2018'))
print(convert2('Mon 30th Sep 2018'))

print(convert1('01st Sep 2018'))
print(convert2('Sun 02nd Sep 2018'))
```

This is the output:

```
2018-09-30 00:00:00
2018-09-30 00:00:00
2018-09-01 00:00:00
2018-09-02 00:00:00
```

I used the patterns as described [in the documentation for datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior). I used [sclicing](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-index-and-slice-strings-in-python-3) to extract the `th` part of the date-string. In doing so I ensure that the functions also work for `nd` and `st`.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to convert from `30th Sep 2018` or `Mon 30th Sep 2018` to `2018-09-30 00:00:00` is using [`dateutil.parser`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html), i.e.:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
d = "30th Sep 2018"
dd = "Mon 30th Sep 2018"
print parse(d)
print parse(dd)
# 2018-09-30 00:00:00
# 2018-09-30 00:00:00
```

---

For the opposite conversion, there's [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html), but I'm afraid it doesn't output ordinals (1st, 2nd) as you want, still, you can achieve the desired result using a [small function](http://germanylandofinnovation.com/questions/28893/python-format-datetime-mit-st-nd-rd-th-engl-ordinal-suffix-wie-php-s-s), i.e.:

```
def ord(n):
    return str(n)+("th" if 4<=n%100<=20 else {1:"st",2:"nd",3:"rd"}.get(n%10, "th"))
x = datetime.datetime.strptime("2018-09-30 00:00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print "{} {}".format(ord(int(x.strftime('%d'))), x.strftime('%b %Y'))
# 30th Sep 2018
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(datetime.strftime('%Y %m %d %X)
```

You can use **strftime** for change the style of date and time

Goto to

> http://strftime.org/

For more inforamtion